# Diagonalization of Singular Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have $n\times n$ matrix $M$ such that this matrix is singular i.e $\det(M) = 0$ and $M$ is symmetric i.e $M = \text{transpose}(M)$ but not diagonal. Now what we can say about the its eigenvalues, can we say that such matrix will not have $n$ distinct eigenvalues?

**2nd thing** if a matrix does not have $n$ distinct eigenvalues and matrix is not diagonal then can we say that such matrix will not have $n$ independent eigenvectors?

If above $2$ conditions holds can we say we cannot diagonalize such matrix?

Regards
Ahsan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your first question: every symmetric matrix (with real entries) is diagonalizable, and symmetric matrices can have real eigenvalues with any multiplicity.  A matrix is singular if and only if $0$ is one of its eigenvalues.

To your second question: consider as a counter-example
$$
\pmatrix{1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1}
$$
this matrix is diagonalizable, and it has eigenvalues $\{0,0,3\}$.

Comment: actually it should be in conjunction with 1st condition i.e matrix should be singular with repeated eigenvalues

Comment: See my latest edit.